# Loops in Function Not Working Proplerly

Tags: php

Could somebody by any chance help me cleanup this function and make it work properly?

It is supposed to look like this: http://gyazo.com/04c31a3edaabeca5f5c6376f1cb607ca.png
Except under category it should only list the categories matching up with the cat_id which does work.

But the page looks weird.
This is what it looks like now: http://gyazo.com/f217603bede98210dce21328e1aab34f.png

```
function getcatposts($cat_id) 
{
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `topics`");
    if(!$sql){
      echo 'Error: ',mysql_error();
    }
    $r = mysql_fetch_row($sql);

    $numrows = $r[0];
    $rowsperpage = 10;

    $totalpages = ceil($numrows / $rowsperpage);

    echo '
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">  
        <thead>  
          <tr class="info">  
            <th>Title</th>  
            <th>Username</th>  
            <th>Date</th>  
            <th>Category</th>  
          </tr>  
        </thead>';
    if(isset($_GET['currentpage']) && is_numeric($_GET['currentpage'])) {
       $currentpage = (int) $_GET['currentpage'];
    } else {
       $currentpage = 1;
    }

    if($currentpage > $totalpages) {
       $currentpage = $totalpages;
    }

    if($currentpage < 1) {
      $currentpage = 1;
    }

    $offset = ($currentpage - 1) * $rowsperpage;

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `topics` ORDER BY topic_id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage");
    if(!$sql){
      echo 'Error: '.mysql_error();
    }
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "lunar_lunar", "", "lunar_users");
    $qc = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM topics WHERE topic_cat='$cat_id'");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qc)) 
    {
      $topic_title[]=$row['topic_subject'];
      $topic_id[]=$row['topic_id'];
    }

    $qc2 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id='$cat_id'");

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($qc2)) 
    {
      $cat_name[]=$row2['cat_name'];
    }
    for ($i=0; $i < count($topic_id); $i++) 
    {
      echo '
        <tbody><tr>
          <td><a href="topic.php?id='.$topic_id[$i].'">'.$topic_title[$i].'</a></td>
          <td><a href="../public.php?id='.$res['topic_by'].'">'.getOwner($res['topic_by']).'</td></a>
          <td>'.$res['topic_date'].'</td>
          <td>'.$cat_name[$i].'</td>
        </tr></tbody>
            ';
    }
}
```

Comment: Both links redirect to the same page. At least for me.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you need to be logged in, Ill update with screenshots.

Comment: Not totally relevant to your question but mysql_* functions are deprecated due to security concerns.  Use PDO or mysqli instead and use a prepared statement for your pagination query, it's vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I used mysqli for most of it but didn't finish the function yet, you think that you could fix it up a bit?

Comment: Also, $res isn't defined anywhere, that could be why topic by and topic date aren't showing anything.  can you do a print_r of $cat_name before the final forloop to see if it was populated?

Comment: This won't fix your function, but you asked for code cleanup advice indirectly so: put all of your database calls at the top of the function, all of your variable definitions right afterwards, and all of the output at the end. Right now it's a bit mixed together and harder to find things.

Comment: Thanks @Snowburnt I fixed that issue! And yes it displays only 1 thing which is the correct data. Says [0] => Website Development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't see where $res was defined, that would explain why topic by and topic date aren't showing anything. Maybe you forgot to change the variable name?

second you're selecting the name of a particular category, so there will only be one result row.  When you cycle through the topics you'll display the first one but cat_name[1] and cat_name[2] will be empty. Since you know that you're only selecting a single category, just assign the result to a variable rather than array. cat_name instead of cat_name[]

you say:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_id='$cat_id'
```

assuming cat_id is the primary key of the table you will NEVER have more than one result.

When you assign it to the cat_name[] you go like this:

```
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($qc2)) 
    {
      $cat_name[]=$row2['cat_name'];
    }
```

it will fetch one row and assign it to $cat_name[0].

The problem comes here:

```
<td>'.$cat_name[$i].'</td>
```

inside the loop $i is incrementing, and it will go through 3 times in this case. $cat_name[0] will return "web development".  But $cat_name[1] and $cat_name[2] will have nothing.  either just call $cat_name[0] instead of $cat_name[$i] or assign the value to just plain $cat_name and call that in the loop.

Comment: Nevermind, I understand now. But can you help me with the issue that it is displaying it under the footer for some reason when I call the function way above the footer?

Comment: Thankyou! Now all the data displays correctly, its just when I call the function above the footer it displays way below, any idea why? I can pastebin the whole document if ud like,

Comment: you didn't give us enough information to fix that.  it probably has to do with how the div positioning is set up or some other HTML formatting issue.
can you show us the finished output HTML?

Comment: The page or the code? Ill just put both.

http://pastebin.com/vvRHHkyA

http://gyazo.com/695185725c7cf77d5d2fef6d1626d901

Comment: The in-browser HTML output is this: http://pastebin.com/FbiqCiLs

I believe thats as much info as I can give D:

Comment: It looks like you didn't close the table tag add: echo '</table>' to right before the end of your function

Comment: O.O Thanks so much for this Snowburnt! You're amazing!